# The variable count here, is declared after initialization, what is this concept called in JAVA, where can I read more about it?

Tags: java

public class ABC {

```
{
    count = 1;
}

int count =3;
```

}//end of class

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks help? Also, Java is not an acronym, so it should not be written in all caps.

Comment: Found another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215842/why-can-my-instance-initializer-block-reference-a-field-before-it-is-declared